# Print the name of the column in a loop in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, html-table

So if I have a loop in PHP and printing the names of the columns such as:

```
<?php foreach ($allColumns as $columnValues): ?>
            <th scope="col">

                <?php echo $columnValues ?>

                <button type="submit" name="exchange">
                   <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt" style="float: right; cursor: pointer"></i>
                </button>

            </th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So I will have a table like this

[image]

So whenever I click on one of the exchange icons, I want to print the name of that column.
How do I do this?

**UPDATE**:
printing it is not the main point.I just want to find a way to get that specific column and not all of them. Because if I try to print it inside the loop it will print all of them and outside the loop I don't have access to $columnValues

Comment: Print the column name where? Somewhere in the screen? On a local printer? Network printer?

Comment: Something like `onclick="alert(this.parentElement.innerText.strip())"`?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Just echo it. Does not matter where. I just want to find a way to get that specific column and not all of them. Because if I try to print it inside the loop it will print all of them and outside the loop I don't have access to $columnValues

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @u_mulder The real problem is that I want the columns to move (switch) when the user clicks on the exchange icons. I have that set up. I have the function:
 function moveColumn($tb , $col1 , $col2) and col1 and col2 switch places. The only problem is I don't know how to tell the program which icon is being clicked.

so when I want to call that function, It would be moveColumn('tablename' , allColumns[i] , allColumns[i+1]) and I is the index of the column clicked